# How do I insert commas from a code pointing to a website(python)

Tags: python-3.x

This my code, trying to figure out how to insert commas to a variable that is constantly changing.

```py
def covid(): #covid-19 cases
    r = requests.get('http://coronavirus-19-api.herokuapp.com/all')
    
    data = r.json()
    covid_data = f'Total confirmed cases is {data["cases"]}\n Current deaths is {data["deaths"]}\n Total people that recovered is {data["recovered"]}'
    print(covid_data)
    speak(covid_data)
```

Comment: Please explain about the commas. I do not see any commas here. Do you want to format large integers? If so, is localization important?

Comment: The numbers come from the web link I inserted in my code. The variables change hourly and I've been trying to figure out how to insert commas into my code

Answer (score 0):

You could insert commas into an integer every three characters with a really simple line of code!

```
{number:,}
```

For example, if we wanted to turn `500000` into `500,000` we would do `{500000:,}` within our f-string.

Your code properly updated for this would be:

```
def covid(): # Covid-19 Cases
    r = requests.get("https://coronavirus-19-api-herokuapp.com/all")
    
    data = r.json()
    covid_data = f"Total confirmed cases is {data['cases']:,}\nCurrent deaths is {data['deaths']:,}\nTotal people that recovered is {data['recovered']:,}"
    print(covid_data)
    speak(covid_data)
```

I hope I properly understand and answered your problem!

Comment: I that the first thing I tried out and when I run it and to to the covid section, my code times out because of the :, in the f-string

Comment: Could you send your error, no idea why that would happen?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 170, in _new_conn
(self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
 for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
 File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\socket.py", line 743, in getaddrinfo
 for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

Comment: The covid section is 6 lines of code and is located between lines 139-145. My line 73 just has comments and notes so it shouldn't pick that up and there is no line 743